# [For Loop]error when knitting in R: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r

When I run my code in R it was fine but when I was trying to knit it, there is an error code:

Error in approc[I] <- 4*s: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Write an R program to approximate π using the first n terms of the Leibniz formula:

```
n <- 50
s=0
sign = 1
for (i in 0:n){
  s = s+sign/(2*i+1)
  sign = -sign
  approx[i] <- 4 * s
}
approx
plot(approx, type="l", col="blue")
abline(h=pi, lty=2)
tail(approx, 1)
```

Comment: Your code is not reproducible. What is `approx` and how was it initialized? Are you sure `approx` is something like a vector, and not, say, a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't defined `approx` before attempting to save values into it. `approx` also happens to be the name of a base R function, so when you attempt to index (subset) a function (which has type `closure`) you get [the iconic R error](https://rstudio.com/resources/rstudioconf-2020/object-of-type-closure-is-not-subsettable/) that "object of type closure is not subsettable". Try including `approx <- numeric(n)` before calling your for loop and it should be fine.

Comment: thank you it helps!

Comment: Oh good! Feel free to upvote or hit the green check so others know it's helpful as well.